# Macro changes output

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment, tabu

The code and output shown below are based on the answers to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62642/multiple-pairs-of-columns/62702) .

The problem is that first of the three tables is produced as desired but the
second and third have the second column vertically centered which is not 
desired.  This is despite the fact that all three are the same except for 
the use of macros in the second and third to reduce redundancy.  Somehow the
introduction of these macros has changed the output.  What is going on?  How
can I fix that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This table just repeats all the required commands
for each row.  The output appears as desired.

\begin{center}\small
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\renewcommand\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{tabu} {>{\bfseries}lX}
\savetabu{mytabu}
Name1 & Value1. \\
\tabucline[blue]-
\end{tabu}

\begin{tabu} {\usetabu{mytabu}}
Name2 & Value2. \\
\tabucline[blue]-
\end{tabu}

\begin{tabu} {\usetabu{mytabu}}
Name3 & Value3. \\
\tabucline[blue]-
\end{tabu}

\end{multicols}
\end{center}

This table uses the RowA macro defined using a \LaTeX{} macro.  The second
column of the table is vertically centered which is not desirable.

\newcommand{\RowA}[1]{
    \begin{tabu}{\usetabu{mytabu}}
    #1 \\
    \tabucline[blue]-\end{tabu}
}

\begin{center}\small
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\renewcommand\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{tabu} {>{\bfseries}lX}\savetabu{mytabu}
Name1 & Value1. \\
\tabucline[blue]-
\end{tabu}

\RowA{Name2 & Value2.}

\RowA{Name3 & Value3.}

\end{multicols}
\end{center}

This table uses the RowB macro defined using a \TeX{} macro.  The second
column of the table is vertically centered which is not desirable.

\def\RowB#1{
\begin{tabu} {\usetabu{mytabu}}
#1 \\
\tabucline[blue]-\end{tabu}
}
\begin{center}\small
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\renewcommand\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{tabu} {>{\bfseries}lX}\savetabu{mytabu}
Name1 & Value1. \\
\tabucline[blue]-
\end{tabu}

\RowB{Name2 & Value2.}

\RowB{Name3 & Value3.}

\end{multicols}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard answer to a large percentage of TeX questions:

Missing `%` at end of lines.....

```
\newcommand{\RowA}[1]{%
    \begin{tabu}{\usetabu{mytabu}}%
    #1\\%
    \tabucline[blue]-\end{tabu}%
}


\def\RowB#1{%
\begin{tabu} {\usetabu{mytabu}}%
#1\\%
\tabucline[blue]-\end{tabu}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works.  Why is it needed?  Also why is it that the Row macro in this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62642/multiple-pairs-of-columns/62702#62702 works without trailing % characters?

Comment: The question referenced also inserts lots of spurious space characters, if they had no effect in the output, it just got lucky.

Comment: I understand the difference between putting in trailing % characters and not (i.e. whitespace swallowing) but don't understand why it should matter when the first table shown in my question that does not use macros has no trailing % characters.