# Making a multiple column table in this fashion

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like this:

> Title Name        Title Name
>
> ---
>
> Mr     Tom            Mr    Tim
>
> Mrs    Eliza         Mr    Ohm

so I want a table with multiple columns, but I don't want to input the LaTeX code like

> Mr &Tom &Mr &Tim
>
> (etc)

but instead I want to input it like:

> Mr &Tom
>
> Mrs &Eliza
>
> (some code)
>
> Mr &Tim
>
> Mr &Ohm

Is it possible to do this? I want to do it like this because it is much easier to read when the data for one person is contained in just one, rather than having two people on one line. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, the backslash was a mistake. I will edit the explanation a bit.

Comment: So, you want to input the data column-like, not line by line?

Comment: Does this help? [Automatic way to break narrow tables into two columns?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27088)

Comment: @Johannes_B Not quite, see the link for what I wanted.

Comment: AAhh, ok. So i guess this question is a duplicate of the other?

Comment: @Johannes_B I guess, unless there's a simpler solution :)

Comment: You can place a carriage return within your code above `Mr &Tom &Mr &Tim` if your only problem is wanting a single name per line of code.  For example, between the second `&` and the second `Mr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps placing two tabulars side-by-side will work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Title & Name \\ \hline
Mr    & Tom \\
Mrs   & Eliza \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Title & Name \\ \hline
Mr    & Tim \\
Mr    & Ohm \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]