# latex table to continue on the same page

Tags: tables, csv

I need to generate a latex table using data from a csv file. The table has only two columns with about 500 rows. I would like to make best use of the space and continue the table on the same page, before moving onto the next page. Any directions please?

Thanks, 
Sam

Comment: Maybe print on a roll of papyrus :o) You won't be limited. Seriously, how do you want a single sheet of paper to contain 500 lines?

Comment: Question is not so clear.  Do you want directions on how to make a basic table? use csv for your table? Or just to make an extra, extra long page for your table to be placed?  If you have made any concrete attempts thus far, please share your code in your answer using the code block tools to highlight them in gray. No judgment here as to why you might want to do this ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are examples of how to split a long narrow table into two ([Automatic way to break narrow tables into two columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27088/automatic-way-to-break-narrow-tables-into-two-columns/)), but I don't know if that would work so well in your case.

Depending on exactly what you need in terms of layout, you could possibly use a simple `itemize` list in a `multicols` environment, in combination with e.g. `datatool`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{500.txt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{itemize}
\DTLforeach{data}{\a=a,\b=b}{\item[\a]\quad \b}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

where `500.txt` goes like

```
a,b
0,0
1,1
2,4
3,9
4,16
5,25
```

and so on for 500 lines.

[image]