# Dealing with very long table - split into columns?

Tags: tables, columns

I've got a very long table in a document that I'm not sure how to deal with. I've been thinking about putting it in the appendix of my document (I'd have to create one just for the table). It's too long to place directly in the text (it takes up a page). Is there a way of maybe putting half of the table in one "column" and the other half in another without making two columns for the text?

Cheers!

This is the table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Anfalljahr & Abwicklungsjahr & Standardfehler \\
\midrule 
1 & 9 & 650,1919 \\ 
\midrule
2 & 8 & 875,4824 \\
2 & 9 & 671,2845 \\
\midrule 
3 & 7 & 1170,6342 \\
3 & 8 & 901,8521 \\
3 & 9 & 691,6597 \\
\midrule
4 & 6 & 1559,5708 \\
4 & 7 & 1203,8834 \\
4 & 8 & 927.5346 \\
4 & 9 & 711,4804 \\
\midrule
5 & 5 & 2071,7564 \\
5 & 6 & 1606,1098 \\
5 & 7 & 1239,1049 \\
5 & 8 & 954,6539 \\
5 & 9 & 732,4417 \\
\midrule
6 & 4 & 2698,5804 \\
6 & 5 & 2151,6863 \\
6 & 6 & 1665,0242 \\
6 & 7 & 1283,5693 \\
6 & 8 & 989,0181 \\
6 & 9 & 759,1276 \\
\midrule
7 & 3 & 3423,2954 \\
7 & 4 & 2855,1991 \\
7 & 5 & 2267,2416 \\
7 & 6 & 1749,4723 \\
7 & 7 & 1347,3335 \\
7 & 8 & 1038.4542 \\
7 & 9 & 797,6345 \\
\midrule
8 & 2 & 4299,1644 \\
8 & 3 & 3767,7121 \\
8 & 4 & 3110,0573 \\
8 & 5 & 2446,4490 \\
8 & 6 & 1875,8567 \\
8 & 7 & 1440,5486 \\
8 & 8 & 1109,7732 \\
8 & 9 & 852,8231 \\
\midrule
9 & 1 & 5648,2843 \\
9 & 2 & 5186,1165 \\
9 & 3 & 4445,4462 \\
9 & 4 & 3574,7993 \\
9 & 5 & 2745,5721 \\
9 & 6 & 2068,0585 \\
9 & 7 & 1571,5864 \\
9 & 8 & 1204,7393 \\
9 & 9 & 924,0199 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Standardfehler für die geschätzten Schadenzuwächse}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You can split by having two tabular environments (just don't leave any empty line betwen them.

Comment: related information: [break a table on two columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64357/579), [break a table on two columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7702/579), [Making a long table continue over two columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23488/579)

Comment: in particular to use longtable see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex

Answer (score 21):

The easiest is to split the data into two tabulars.

```
\begin{tabular}{..}
...
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{..}
...
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

See code at [MWE](https://github.com/yannisl/MWE/blob/master/two-tables.tex).

Comment: I just tried that but for some reason it still doesn't place them next to each other. This is the bit that ends the first tabular and begins the next one. \end{tabular} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Anfalljahr & Abwicklungsjahr & Standardfehler \\

Comment: Are you leaving a blank line in between?

Comment: it is \begin{tabular}[t]{..} you need to use Jonas

Comment: How do you get these to be vertically aligned at the top? Splitting the tabulars into two and placing them next to each other works for me but the top \hlines are not vertically aligned...

Comment: @Constantin The full minimal is available. Just click on the MWE.

Comment: @Constantin Put [t] parameter after \tabular: `\begin{tabular}[t]`

Answer (score 10):

I used `minipage` and `vdots` and got the effect I wanted:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\caption{Your Caption}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical} \\
\midrule
0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical}  \\
\midrule
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
99  &  0.0  &  7.88-29  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent solution with a comprehensive MWE - thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

The MWE supplied by the original answer uses `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` on the first line. This will cause the entire document to be presented in two column form.

A more minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
\hline
Anfalljahr & Abwicklungsjahr & Standardfehler \\
\hline 
1 & 9 & 650,1919 \\ 
\hline
2 & 8 & 875,4824 \\
2 & 9 & 671,2845 \\
\hline 
3 & 7 & 1170,6342 \\
3 & 8 & 901,8521 \\
3 & 9 & 691,6597 \\
\hline
4 & 6 & 1559,5708 \\
4 & 7 & 1203,8834 \\
4 & 8 & 927.5346 \\
4 & 9 & 711,4804 \\
\hline
9 & 1 & 5648,2843 \\
9 & 2 & 5186,1165 \\
9 & 3 & 4445,4462 \\
9 & 4 & 3574,7993 \\
9 & 5 & 2745,5721 \\
9 & 6 & 2068,0585 \\
9 & 7 & 1571,5864 \\
9 & 8 & 1204,7393 \\
9 & 9 & 924,0199 \\
\hline
5 & 5 & 2071,7564 \\
5 & 6 & 1606,1098 \\
5 & 7 & 1239,1049 \\
5 & 8 & 954,6539 \\
5 & 9 & 732,4417 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
\hline
Anfalljahr & Abwicklungsjahr & Standardfehler \\
\hline 
6 & 4 & 2698,5804 \\
6 & 5 & 2151,6863 \\
6 & 6 & 1665,0242 \\
6 & 7 & 1283,5693 \\
6 & 8 & 989,0181 \\
6 & 9 & 759,1276 \\
\hline
7 & 3 & 3423,2954 \\
7 & 4 & 2855,1991 \\
7 & 5 & 2267,2416 \\
7 & 6 & 1749,4723 \\
7 & 7 & 1347,3335 \\
7 & 8 & 1038.4542 \\
7 & 9 & 797,6345 \\
\hline
8 & 2 & 4299,1644 \\
8 & 3 & 3767,7121 \\
8 & 4 & 3110,0573 \\
8 & 5 & 2446,4490 \\
8 & 6 & 1875,8567 \\
8 & 7 & 1440,5486 \\
8 & 8 & 1109,7732 \\
8 & 9 & 852,8231 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The key elements are the [t] argument given to both tabular environments in order to make both table align at the top. If you need more control than this, you can turn to minipages. http://texblog.org/2007/08/01/placing-figurestables-side-by-side-minipage/