# How to vertically align tables with different row counts?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, booktabs

I obtained this code from a [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134381/dealing-with-very-long-table-split-into-columns). However, when the number of rows in the two tables are different, the tables become misaligned. How can I align them at the top? I attempted using the command `\begin{tabular}[t]`, but it did not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\caption{Your Caption}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical} \\
\midrule
0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical}  \\
\midrule
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
99  &  0.0  &  7.88-29  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Either remove the minipages so that the `[t]` option of the tabulars can do their job

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{table} 
   \caption{Your Caption}

   %\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
   \toprule
   \textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical} \\
   \midrule
   0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
   0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   %
   %\end{minipage} \hfill
   %\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
   \toprule
   \textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical}  \\
   \midrule
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
   99  &  0.0  &  7.88-29  \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}

   %\end{minipage}
   \end{table}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Align the minipages at the top:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{table} 
   \caption{Your Caption}

   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
   \toprule
   \textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical} \\
   \midrule
   0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
   0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}

   \end{minipage} \hfill
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
   \toprule
   \textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical}  \\
   \midrule
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
   99  &  0.0  &  7.88-29  \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}

   \end{minipage}
   \end{table}
   \end{document}
   ```