# Split a long thin vertical table into 2 columns automatically

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, split

I have a long thin table that is filling a whole page. I think that splitting the table into two columns I can take advantage of the space on the page. However I'm still trying to do it automatically without success. Any help?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[%
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
%
\begin{table}[htb]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{cSSS}
\cmidrule{2-4}
& \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} \\
\midrule
\multirow{15}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Series 1}}}
& 0           & 0,1           & 101,4       \\
& 0,25        & 0,2           & 88,9        \\
& 0           & 0,3           & 76,2        \\
& 0,55        & 0,4           & 63,5        \\
& 1           & 0,5           & 50,8        \\
& 0,85        & 0,6           & 44,4        \\
& 1           & 0,7           & 38,1        \\
& 1,15        & 0,8           & 31,7        \\
& 1           & 0,9           & 25,4        \\
& 1,45        & 1,0           & 19,1        \\
& 2           & 1,5           & 15,9        \\
& 1,75        & 2,0           & 12,7        \\
& 2           & 2,5           & 9,52        \\
& 2,05        & 2,75          & 7,93        \\
& 2           & 3,0           & 6,35        \\
\midrule
\multirow{31}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Series 2}}}
& 3,5         & 3,5         & 5,66        \\
& 4           & 4           & 4,76        \\
& 5           & 5           & 4,00        \\
& 6           & 6           & 3,36        \\
& 7           & 7           & 2,83        \\
& 8           & 8           & 2,38        \\
& 10          & 10          & 2,00        \\
& 12          & 12          & 1,65        \\
& 14          & 14          & 1,41        \\
& 16          & 16          & 1,19        \\
& 18          & 18          & 1,00        \\
& 20          & 20          & 0,84        \\
& 25          & 25          & 0,71        \\
& 30          & 30          & 0,59        \\
& 35          & 35          & 0,50        \\
& 40          & 40          & 0,42        \\
& 45          & 45          & 0,35        \\
& 50          & 50          & 0,297       \\
& 60          & 60          & 0,250       \\
& 70          & 70          & 0,210       \\
& 80          & 80          & 0,177       \\
& 100         & 100         & 0,149       \\
& 120         & 120         & 0,125       \\
& 140         & 140         & 0,105       \\
& 170         & 170         & 0,088       \\
& 200         & 200         & 0,074       \\
& 230         & 230         & 0,062       \\
& 270         & 270         & 0,053       \\
& 325         & 325         & 0,044       \\
& 400         & 400         & 0,037       \\
& 500         & 500         & 0,025       \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23599/586 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65845/586 be helpful?

Comment: Some more related questions:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134381/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64356/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7702/134144